# Echarts - dual YAsix not working with different min/max values

Tags: echarts, yaxis

I have a chart with average CPU (AVG-CPU) and Max CPU (MAX_CPU).  AVG-CPU is BAR while MAX-CPU is Line chart.   I'm trying to use 2 yaxis (left is AVG_CPU / right is MAX_CPU).   However, when I change min/max on the yaxis for AVG_CPU in order to scale it better, the MAX_CPU lines go off the chart (they don't show anymore).

Here is the code w/o scaling AVG-CPU

```
        yAxis: [
          {
              id:   'AvgAxis',
              type: 'value',
              name: 'Average CPU %',
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              interval: 10,
              axisLabel: {
                  formatter: '{value} %'
              }
          },
          {
              id:   'MaxAxis',
              type: 'value',
              name: 'Max CPU %',
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              interval: 10,
              axisLabel: {
                  formatter: '{value} %'
              }      }
      ]
```

Here is results:
[image]

Here is code when I try to scale the AVG-CPU

```
        yAxis: [
          {
              id:   'AvgAxis',
              type: 'value',
              name: 'Average CPU %',
              min: 0,
              max: 50,
              interval: 5,
              axisLabel: {
                  formatter: '{value} %'
              }
          },
          {
              id:   'MaxAxis',
              type: 'value',
              name: 'Max CPU %',
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              interval: 10,
              axisLabel: {
                  formatter: '{value} %'
              }      }
      ],
```

And here is the results:
[image]

Note that the MAX_CPU lines are gone.  They seem to be off the chart because I scaled the AVG-CPU.

Any Ideas or suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Could you provide full code? Divination by screenshots it's not the best choice for spent time. In a lot of cases it is very difficult to reproduce the problem without original code.

You can take this template and fill it own data. http://jsfiddle.net/Lk0ejcdg/

Comment: Here is the link to the example in fiddle.   http://jsfiddle.net/6pkmaz7v/

Comment: Change the AvgAxis.Max = 30 and AvgAxis.interval=5.   The max line disappears.

Answer (score 2):

@JimRitchhart, both series use the same yAxis and `type: 'line'` just didn't fit in new range in view frame when you change max value. For display both series need explicitly bind each to yAxis index.

```js
series: [{
  type: 'bar',
  yAxisIndex: 0,
  //...
},
{
  type: 'line',
  yAxisIndex: 1,
  //...
}]
```

```js
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
  var option = {
      title: {
          text: 'ECharts'
      },
      tooltip: {},
      legend: {
          data:['Label']
      },
      xAxis: {
          data: ["Category1","Category2","Category3","Category4","Category5","Category6"]
      },
      yAxis: [
          {
              id:   'AvgAxis',
              type: 'value',
              name: 'Average CPU %',
              min: 0,
              max: 30,
              interval: 5,
              axisLabel: { formatter: '{value} %' }
          },
          {
              id:   'MaxAxis',
              type: 'value',
              name: 'Max CPU %',
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              interval: 10,
              axisLabel: { formatter: '{value} %' }
         }
      ],
      series: [{
        yAxisIndex: 0,
          name: 'Average',
          type: 'bar',
          data: [5, 7, 4, 3, 4, 6],
      },
        {
         yAxisIndex: 1,
          name: 'Max',
          type: 'line',
          data: [65, 80, 96, 70, 70, 80],
        }
      ]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts-en.common.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Beautiful - Thank you !!    Worked like a champ.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much. Why didn't the topic owner mark this is the correct answer ? What a pity.